# Inserting a JSON value into a mysql but 0 is being inserted

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am creating a python API that will take values from a user in the form of a JSON object and insert these values into a database. Instead of inserting the data, a 0 is being inserted while the id increments as expected. Would anyone be able to advise me as to how to solve this problem?

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO `player`(`player_id`,`Name`, `Age`, `Overall`, `Position`) " \
      "VALUES ('', `Name`=%s,`Age`=%s,`Overall`=%s,`Position`=%s);"

cursor.execute(sql, (request.json['Name'], request.json['Age'],
                     request.json['Overall'], request.json['Position']))

cnx.commit()
```

The code above is what I am currently using. All help is appreciated

Comment: `0` is inserted where? Every value?

Comment: Yes, every value apart from `player_id` which auto increments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NULL` for auto incrementing fields, and don't specify the name of the field in the VALUES below:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO `player`(`player_id`,`Name`, `Age`, `Overall`, `Position`) " \
      "VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s);"

cursor.execute(sql, (request.json['Name'], request.json['Age'],
                     request.json['Overall'], request.json['Position']))

cnx.commit()
```